# AlpineJs - iterate only not null values

Tags: laravel-8, alpine.js

I'm using Laravel8 with AlpineJs2. I want to make a conditional dropdown using Alpine.
I have 2 issues:

1. I want to render a customClass for each children select eg. :class="selectChild{parent.id}"
2. I want to render the select only if parent.children.length > 0

Thank you for your answers

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Parent1 Name',
        'children' => [],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Parent2 Name',
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Parent2Child1 Name',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Parent2Child2 Name',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'Parent2Child3 Name',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Parent3 Name',
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Parent3Child1 Name',
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Parent3Child1 Name',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

and the template:

```
    <div class="row"
         x-cloak
         x-data="{
            data: {{ json_encode($data) }}
         }"
    >
        <div class="col-4">
            <select class="form-select selectParent">
            <template x-for="parent in data" :key="parent.id">
                <option :value="parent.id" x-text="parent.name"></option>
            </template>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <template x-for="parent in data" :key="parent.id">
                <select x-if="parent.children.length"  :class="selectChild{parent.id}"  class="form-select">
                    <template x-for="child in parent.children" :key="child.id">
                        <option :value="child.id" x-text="child.name"></option>
                    </template>
                </select>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I found so far:

```
<select x-show="parent.children.length" :class="`form-select selectChild${parent.id}`">
   <template x-for="child in parent.children" :key="child.id">
      <option :value="child.id" x-text="child.name"></option>
   </template>
</select>
```

I'm happy with the className, but I don't like that fact that I have to render an element and hide it...